# convert JSON to parallel array Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

i have a unique requirement to be solved. The following is the elasticsearch response from a dummy dataset, as you can see in the result, the columns **accidents** and **accident_date**, **painted** & **preowned** is returned for a row where there is actual value while when the column value is null the field itself is not appearing in the response, this is because elasticsearch does not index null columns.

> A null value cannot be indexed or searched. When a field is set to
> null, (or an empty array or an array of null values) it is treated as
> though that field has no values.

```
var data = 
{
    "result": [
      {
        "totalHits": 3,
        "hits": [
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "baseVersion": 24,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61123"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "painted": "Yes",                        --> note this
                "date_used": 1597017600000,
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          },
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "baseVersion": 24,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61124"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "accidents": "1",                       --> note this
                "accidents_date": "12/12/2019",         --> note this
                "date_used": 1597017600000
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          },
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "baseVersion": 24,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61125"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "preowned": "Yes",                      --> note this
                "date_used": 1597017600000
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": {},
        "nextPageToken": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to parse this information to a Javascript Object where the data appears in parallel arrays, where each array represents a column and the index of the array the value for a given row.
Following is my code, i am using Lodesh to map it first and then performing interation to get the result.

```
var rawData= _.map(data.result.[0].hits, h => h.row)

var primaryKeys=Object.keys(rawData[0].primaryKey);

var columns=Object.keys(rawData[0].columns);

var parsedData={}

for (var pkey of primaryKeys) { parsedData[pkey]=[] }

for (var column of columns) { parsedData[column]=[] }

for (var row of rawData) {
    for (var pkey of primaryKeys) {
        parsedData[pkey].push(row.primaryKey[pkey])
    }
    
    for (var column of columns) {
        parsedData[column].push(row.columns[column])
    }
}

console.log(parsedData);
```

This is the result

```
{
  "car_registration_no": [
    "61123",
    "61124",
    "61125"
  ],
  "model": [
    "Nissan",
    "Nissan",
    "Nissan"
  ],
  "submodel": [
    "Saloon",
    "Saloon",
    "Saloon"
  ],
  "date_used": [
    1597017600000,
    1597017600000,
    1597017600000
  ]
}
```

In my result i am loosing the columns **accidents** and **accident_date**, **painted** & **preowned** because not all row/primaryKey have these columns, I am not able to tell which row will have which column with value, therefore how can i iterate over each row for the primaryKey and map all columns, whenever a row does not have the column that is there in other row for each primaryKey, to generate null value for it in that index for that row.

The expected result is this :

```
{
  "car_registration_no": [
    "61123",
    "61124",
    "61125"
  ],
  "model": [
    "Nissan",
    "Nissan",
    "Nissan"
  ],
  "submodel": [
    "Saloon",
    "Saloon",
    "Saloon"
  ],
  "painted": [
    "Yes",
    "null",              --> note this
    "null"
  ],
  "accidents": [
    "null",              --> note this
    "1",
    "null"
  ],
  "accidents_date": [
    "null",
    "12/12/2019",       --> note this
    "null"
  ],
  "preowned": [
    "null",
    "null",             --> note this
    "Yes"
  ],
  "date_used": [
    1597017600000,
    1597017600000,
    1597017600000
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no any idea about your application here. But, at the end of the day, if your target is extracting an object of arrays, i think my answer may useful!

Note: Here I used string 'null' as you mentioned above. But using null instead of 'null' may useful in further calculations!

```js
var data = {
  result: [
    {
      totalHits: 3,
      hits: [
        {
          schemaid: "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
          baseVersion: 24,
          row: {
            primaryKey: {
              car_registration_no: "61123"
            },
            columns: {
              model: "Nissan",
              submodel: "Saloon",
              painted: "Yes",
              date_used: 1597017600000
            },
            editsVersion: 0
          },
          highlight: {}
        },
        {
          schemaid: "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
          baseVersion: 24,
          row: {
            primaryKey: {
              car_registration_no: "61124"
            },
            columns: {
              model: "Nissan",
              submodel: "Saloon",
              accidents: "1",
              accidents_date: "12/12/2019",
              date_used: 1597017600000
            },
            editsVersion: 0
          },
          highlight: {}
        },
        {
          schemaid: "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
          baseVersion: 24,
          row: {
            primaryKey: {
              car_registration_no: "61125"
            },
            columns: {
              model: "Nissan",
              submodel: "Saloon",
              preowned: "Yes",
              date_used: 1597017600000
            },
            editsVersion: 0
          },
          highlight: {}
        }
      ],
      aggregations: {},
      nextPageToken: null
    }
  ]
};

const emptyData = {
  car_registration_no: [],
  model: [],
  submodel: [],
  painted: [],
  accidents: [],
  accidents_date: [],
  preowned: [],
  date_used: []
};

const emptyCheck = val => val ? val : 'null';

const parsedData = data.result[0].hits.reduce((pre, curr) => {
  const { primaryKey, columns } = curr.row;

  pre.car_registration_no.push(primaryKey.car_registration_no);
  pre.model.push(emptyCheck(columns.model));
  pre.submodel.push(emptyCheck(columns.submodel));
  pre.painted.push(emptyCheck(columns.painted));
  pre.accidents.push(emptyCheck(columns.accidents));
  pre.accidents_date.push(emptyCheck(columns.accidents_date));
  pre.preowned.push(emptyCheck(columns.preowned));
  pre.date_used.push(emptyCheck(columns.date_used));

  return pre;
}, emptyData);

console.log(parsedData);
```

Comment: unfortunately my application can only show the data in a table using parallel arrays.This works perfectly thank you , now i have to create a list for all possible columns that may arrise to ensure no column is missed out :)